# I am trying to join 2 tables and wanna fetch the row if it exists but it show me this error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I am trying to get 'admin_id' from 'logs' table against each user in withdraws. admin_id would get if "User Verified" event is created in 'logs' table. 
Here is my logs table

[Logs Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXVuY.png)

As i am Beginner in laravel so i try this code to fetch result

```
   $withdrawals     =   DB::table('withdrawals')
                                ->join('user_accounts AS accounts','withdrawals.user','=','accounts.user_id')
                                ->join('users AS user','user.id','=','withdrawals.user')
                                ->join('admin_logs AS logs','withdrawals.unique_id','=','logs.user_id')
                                ->select('withdrawals.*','accounts.total_deduct','user.awarded_flag','logs.*')
here is problem                             ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                                      $query->where('logs.user_id', 'withdrawals.unique_id')
                                            ->where('logs.event', 'User Verified')
                                            ->orderby('logs.id','DESC')->first();
                                })
                                ->where('user.status','active')
                                ->where('withdrawals.status','Pending')
                                ->where('withdrawals.is_verify', 0)
                                ->orderby('withdrawals.created_at','DESC')
                                ->get();
```

But it gives me following error
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Here is the table that i am fetcing

[WithDraws Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vz6R.png)

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGgWZ.png)

I think the problem is in JOIN.. Bcz both tables have multiple records of same unique_ids

Comment: show me error message

Comment: check the updated question.  error

Comment: I think You'll need `$query->whereColumn('logs.user_id', 'withdrawals.unique_id')`

Comment: its not working mzolee

Comment: It seems Your closure (and generated subselect) is missing a `from` clause. Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved it by raw query

```
$withdrawals = DB::select( DB::raw("select `withdrawals`.*, `accounts`.`total_deduct`, `user`.`awarded_flag`,(select admin_logs.admin_id from admin_logs WHERE admin_logs.user_id=withdrawals.unique_id and admin_logs.event='User Verified' ORDER BY admin_logs.id DESC LIMIT 1) as adminid
        from `withdrawals` 
        inner join `user_accounts` as `accounts` on `withdrawals`.`user` = `accounts`.`user_id` 
        inner join `users` as `user` on `user`.`id` = `withdrawals`.`user`
        and `user`.`status` = 'active' 
        and `withdrawals`.`status` = 'Pending' 
        and `withdrawals`.`is_verify` = 0 order by `created_at` DESC"));
```